# How to create a WCF Service with no structure (XML request and response)

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, soap

In my most recent project, I've been given a WSDL and a sample request to build a web service with. WCF has weak contract first capability, but I did come up with something complicated that might work (I tried a number of tools, the best being WSCF.Blue). The SOAP request headers, unwrapped body, and XSD are unorthodox and I'm afraid that this integration partner will have lots of strange XML issues, so I'd rather, if possible, just have a service that looks something like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    XmlElement DoStuff(XmlElement request);
}
```

instead of...

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [XmlSerializerFormat(SupportFaults = true, Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document, Use = OperationFormatUse.Literal)]
    ResponseType DoStuff(RequestType request);
}
```

A super simplified version of what this SOAP request looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns1:CustomHeader priority="1" txId="1" xmlns:ns1="http://namespace"/>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <UnwrappedRequest creationDateTime="2014-04-21T16:15:37Z" xmlns="http://anothernamespace.com">
            <ns1:SomeDataNode xmlns:ns1="http://namespace">
                <ns1:MoreData AFlag="false" Thingy="Dude">
                </ns1:MoreData>
            </ns1:SomeDataNode>
        </UnwrappedRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The main reason I want to stick with WCF instead of just creating an HTTP handler or something is because we have to use WS-Security also, which includes a bunch of other headers and the session establishing request before the actual API call. I've tried a couple things that almost work, but they exclude the top node of the request and all of it's attributes (the  node in the sample above). I also need the custom header XML. I know you can bind that into an property on the request object, but I want the request to just be a string of XML.

You would think that every framework out there should be able to easily do this and I know that WCF isn't an exception. The thing we all love about WCF is how flexible and powerful it is. The problem is that most of us don't live in WCF and integration, so we don't ever become experts, and I have a timeline to meet. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with WCF, but last I remembered it required a configuration file. You might try another solution like [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/). They have an older open-source version, go to downloads and scroll to the bottom, which I find easy to use and it is free.

Comment: The XML could be put into a CData tag in the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I could have done this by implementing or overriding a bunch of WCF internal interfaces and classes, but I took the easy route and built a custom HttpHandler to handle the soap call. It works perfectly (and it's SUPER fast). The only somewhat challenging piece was building in the WS-Security stuff, but even that wasn't too bad. It is clear to me that the system they were calling from was just performing a custom HTTP post anyway. It's unfortunate that Microsoft's tooling doesn't support such a large number of valid Web Service scenarios. I talked to a few experienced integration experts, and they abandoned WCF for custom solutions in many of their partner integrations. If you are in control of both sides of an integration project, then great, use WCF. If you are working with partners that have a wide variety of technologies to integrate with, be prepared to either become an expert at customizing WCF or find alternate solutions. 
Feel free to send me a message if you are having this same problem and I can share my code with you. There is just too much to paste in here.